Using QGIS tools in the map view
Is it possible to use any QGIS tools (e.g. features selection, editing, identifing) in the additional map view as well as in the main QGIS map view?
Such functionality is not currently implemented?


You can access the canvases via iface.mapCanvases() and then set a MapTool to it. I tried it with several MapTools, unfortunately not all seem to work. But here is a working code snippets using QgsMapToolEmitPoint and QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature :
QgsMapToolEmitPoint :
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from qgis.utils import iface

canvas = iface.mapCanvases()[1] # select the desired canvas
mt = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
mt.canvasClicked.connect(lambda: print('canvas clicked!'))
canvas.setMapTool(mt)

QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature:
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from qgis.utils import iface

canvas = iface.mapCanvases()[1] # select the desired canvas
print(canvas.objectName())
mt = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(canvas, QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test_layer')[0])
mt.featureIdentified.connect(lambda feature: print('feature Identified', feature))
canvas.setMapTool(mt)

